# web page wont display when javascript is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently building a web page and it will not display when i put in the javascript in the head section

this is my code for the head section:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>***************</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#generalAdmissionList").change(function () {
    var selected = $("#generalAdmissionList option:selected").val();
    $('div').hide();
    $('#' + selected).show();
});

$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('div').hide();
});
});
</script>
</head>
```

while using fire bug in firefox the webpage is not giving me any errors and when I take out the javascript the page works.

I have also tested the javascript in jsFiddle and it is working ok

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dobby90/8xeNw/

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Do you by chance, on your real page, have a `div` containing all of the content?

Comment: ya it is in a `div` which contains all the contents for the body of the web page.

Comment: So what do you think `$('div').hide();` does?

Comment: yeah kid, you are hiding everything.

Comment: Thanks lads figured it out.. Long hours of coding make simple mistakes invisable

Comment: @Johnny993 That is certainly true.

Answer (score 0):

This hide all you main div element. Remove this string.

```
$('div').hide();
```